# Customizing the AppCompat Actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

This question has sort of been asked but not really, what I'm looking to do is have a highly customized toolbar for our app, I recently implemented a drawer menu with the AppCompat Actionbar and it works great, except this is what it gives me by default:

[image]

What I'd like to have is something like this (excuse the rushed drawing):
[image]

I'm prefectly capable of doing this in a normal layout, so I'm not looking for advice on how to make the toolbar look like this, what my question is, is how do I start customizing the layout of the toolbar at all? For example, I don't see a way to position the home button (I believe that's what the hambuger menu is called in this case), it seems like a lot of this stuff is built into the appcompat actionbar and I don't see a way of getting around it, basically to summarize, I just want to have multiple rows of controls in the toolbar, and customize the default built in controls of the toolbar, including positioning. Is there a way I can just insert my own layout file into the actionbar and just have a control set to be the button that activates the drawer layouts drawers? That would be the most ideal solution to this problem for my circumstances.

Comment: You can create a custom layout and include it in your activity layout (assuming your style is without actionbar). Then in your Java code you recover the action bar by ID and 'setSupportActionBar()' to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what my question is, is how do I start customizing the layout of the toolbar at all?

You can customize the view of your `SupportActionbar` like this:

1. Create a `ToolbarView.axml` view file for your Actionbar(It's just an example, you can define anything inside):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="300dp">

     <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvShow"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Please Click Me"/>

     <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. In your activity's `onCreate` method, set the custom view of the `SupportActionbar`:

   ```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
       base.OnCreate(bundle);

       // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
       SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
       SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
       SupportActionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.ToolbarView);
       ...
    }
   ```
3. The height of the ActionBar won't change by the content inside, you have to set the height manually in `Style.xml`:

   ```
   <resources>
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <item name="colorPrimary">#5A8622</item>
       <!--Set the ActionBar Size-->
       <item name="actionBarSize">200dp</item>
     </style>
   </resources>
   ```

Comment: Good to know, especially on the height thing. So my only question then is there a way to override the default menu button? For example, adjust margin and padding, swap the bitmap, etc.?

Comment: I figured it out, I went ahead and accepted your answer though because it was still helpful.